# Separating an integer from a Dictionary with multiple integers

Tags: python, string, integer

I can't seem to find a way to separate 'temp' from this dictionary:

```
{'temp_max': 7.0, 'temp_kf': None, 'temp': 4.67, 'temp_min': 3.0}
```

I just need the number 4.67 in this case. Thank you.

using: print(ast.literal_eval(temp)["temp"]) 
the dictionary is returned as temp.

returns: ValueError: malformed string

Code:

```
observation = owm.weather_at_place('London,uk')
w = observation.get_weather()
temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')
print(temp)
print(ast.literal_eval(temp)["temp"])
t = 'temp'
```

Comment: `s["temp"]` - you're welcome

Comment: sorry very new to python, no it's not in double quotes. The dictionary is returned from an api, however I need just the temp as an integer so I can use it as a variable.

Comment: @DeckeldeLange So did you try what the previous comment suggested?

Comment: Quotes, double quotes. Same deal in Python.

Comment: @ djaw yes I tried the first soultion however it didn't work propbably due to the fact I said It was a string

Comment: Please add to your question what exactly you tried and what the error message was. The first solution should work, so please let us see what exactly you tried, you might have made a mistake.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What does `type(temp)` say? Doesn't `print(temp["temp"])` work and print `4.67`?

Comment: @Wiktor yes it works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the actual data type of the `temp` variable is a dictionary.

Thus, to print the value of the `temp` key in the `temp` variable you may use

```
print(temp["temp"])
```

Or, assign it to another variable:

```
temp_val = temp["temp"]
```